# return sub tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
|object|attribute1|attribute2|
|A     |true      |10        |
|B     |false     |15        |
```

and I would like to have a query that returns:

```
|key      |value    |
|Name_A_1 |true     |
|Name_A_2 |10       |
|Name_B_1 |false    |
|Name_B_2 |15       |
```

so basicly I want to convert the object's name twice and append it to each attribute.

**EDIT:**

as  Tim Biegeleisen mentioned, I have type problem here. so I am willing to covert all types to string.

Comment: You have a potential problem, because you are putting `true` into the same column as a number.  You should tell us the types of all columns in your original table.  Also, include any query you have tried already.

Comment: *Why* do you want such a result? Do you want to convert this into JSON or another form on the client perhaps? There are probably far easier ways to do that, eg using a JSON serializer. If you want this for a report, most report tools can handle this too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Or it's really a BIT but the OP just used `true` as a placeholder.

Comment: @GordonLinoff they are not string in my tables but i am willing to convert to string as part of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using `apply`:

```
select ky, val
from t cross apply
     (values ('Name_' + object + '_1', attribute1),
             ('Name_' + object + '_2', cast(attribute1 as varchar(255)))
     ) v(ky, val);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 'Name_' + object + '_1' as key
        attribute1 as value 
 FROM YourTable
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Name_' + object + '_2' as key
        attribute2 as value 
 FROM YourTable
```

Comment: But as Tim said, only work if value are strings because you cant have boolean and integers on the same column

Answer (score 0):

untested, hope this works...

```
SELECT 'Name_' + object + '_' + (CAST(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY attribute1, attribute2)) AS VARCHAR(6)) AS row,
   attribute1, 
   attribute2 
FROM tableName
```